# Structuring convoluted list to the form useful in ListPlot

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

From an excel file, I have the following form of the (raw) data:

```
{{x1, y11, y12, y13, y14}, {x2, y21, y22, y23, y24}, ..., {xn, yn1, yn2, yn3, yn4}}
```

Here, all innermost elements are all real numbers. I want to make a `ListPlot` from points `{xi, yij}` for each `i` and `j`. The points with same j are to be joined by a line segment. Then, I should be able to manipulate the above list, for example as

```
{{{x1, y11}, {x2, y21}, ..., {xn, yn1}}, ..., {{x1, y14}, {x2, y24}, ..., {xn, yn4}}}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
data = {{x1, y11, y12, y13, y14},
        {x2, y21, y22, y23, y24},
        {x3, y31, y32, y33, y34}};

Table[{e[[1]], e[[j + 1]]}, {j, Length@First@data - 1}, {e, data}]

(** {{{x1, y11}, {x2, y21}, {x3, y31}},
     {{x1, y12}, {x2, y22}, {x3, y32}},
     {{x1, y13}, {x2, y23}, {x3, y33}},
     {{x1, y14}, {x2, y24}, {x3, y34}}} **)
```

Comment: Thanks for such a simple answer!

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Format[x[n_]] := Subscript[x, n]
Format[y[m_, n_]] := Subscript[y, Row[{m, n}]]

(data = {{x[1], y[1, 1], y[1, 2], y[1, 3], y[1, 4]},
    {x[2], y[2, 1], y[2, 2], y[2, 3], y[2, 4]},
    {x[3], y[3, 1], y[3, 2], y[3, 3], y[3, 4]},
    {x[4], y[4, 1], y[4, 2], y[4, 3], y[4, 4]},
    {x[5], y[5, 1], y[5, 2], y[5, 3], y[5, 4]}}) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Use a helper function to form the points

```
convertList[lst_?VectorQ] :=
 {First@lst, #} & /@ (Rest@lst)

(data2 = Transpose[convertList /@ data]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

When `data` is defined with numeric values use

```
ListLinePlot[data2]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Thread[{First@#,Rest@#}]&/@data//Transpose

(* {
   {{x1, y11}, {x2, y21}, {x3, y31}}, 
   {{x1, y12}, {x2, y22}, {x3, y32}}, 
   {{x1, y13}, {x2, y23}, {x3, y33}}, 
   {{x1, y14}, {x2, y24}, {x3, y34}}
   } *)
```

Original Answer:

```
Distribute[{First@#, Rest@#},List]&/@data//Transpose
```

Alternative form:

```
 ArrayReduce[Thread[{First@#,Rest@#}]&, data, 2]//Transpose
```

where

```
data = {{x1, y11, y12, y13, y14},
        {x2, y21, y22, y23, y24},
        {x3, y31, y32, y33, y34}};
```